# How to Use the Model from one project in another project in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two projects—let us say ProjectA and ProjectB.

Project A is already in production, but I need to add a functionality. I do not want to include it in ProjectA for security reasons, and also I have to create a separate domain for this functionality. But I want the two to use the same database.

My question are below:

1. how do I use the model in ProjectA in ProjectB.
2. I am using a CodeFirst approach; I hope running ProjectB will not lead to data migration on ProjectA.
3. In the `web.config`, which database connection will be referenced?

Thank you for the anticipated assistance.

Comment: There's no reason you can't put your Entity Framework code first models in a separate project—let's say `ProjectC`—which gets called from both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. Unless your applications are on the same domain or you migrate to a separate service for managing configuration data, you'll likely need to duplicate your connection strings in  both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. As for the migrations, you could add a condition around your migration call within your `DBContext`, or even potentially derive your `DBContext` in `ProjectA` and add your migrations to that version.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a bit of a broad question for Stack Overflow, as there are really three separate questions, which are only loosely related to one another. You may get better results by breaking it up into separate questions. E.g., "How do I share a connection string between multiple projects?"